# PBKDF2 function in Android

Tags: android, pbkdf2

Is there PBKDF2 implementation for Android. I am trying to derive a key using PBKDF2 function. I couldn't find an example to do so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Free options would be:

- http://rtner.de/software/PBKDF2.html
- http://bouncycastle.org/ (that might be newer than some Android-bundled `org.bouncycastle`)
- http://www.unwesen.de/2011/06/12/encryption-on-android-bouncycastle/
- https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle#readme

IF a commercial component is an option see for example http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-encryption.asp (sample code http://www.example-code.com/android/crypt2_pbkdf2.asp).

Another option is to use `javax.crypto` and implement it yourself although I wouldn't recommend that...

Answer (score 17):

Late to the party, but a lot of Android devices DO include PBKDF2 with the standard SecretKeyFactory. However, a lot of people recommend using something like Spongycastle to guarantee that you'll have that algorithm available.

It does throw an exception if it can't find one

```
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;
    try
    {
        keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
```

Comment: The following article includes an example method for the usage of SecretKeyFactory's PBKDF:  http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html (see section "Even more security").

Comment: Works for Android API 10+, as documented at https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html for anyone that wonders