# What is best algorithm for password encryption and decryption for android and web application in google app engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

We have developed an application using google app engine. We have an android and web application which communicates to same database. We have log in functionality.For which we need to encrypt and decrypt the password. We tried few earlier but it's not in sync.It means if we apply it both side then login fails at android side and vice versa.
Can you please suggest us which algorithm will be useful for both side so android and web both will work on same algorithm.

Thanks,

Prashant

Answer (score 1):

I recommend either [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). Both are algorithms especially designed for hashing passwords.

Comment: Thanks Niklas,
Does it work for android and WEB (Java) at both side?

Comment: @Prashanth Yes it does. You can also have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091519/pbkdf2-function-in-android